# sql query 4 tables

Tags: sql

I have these tables

```
create table Customer2 (cid char(3), cname char(10), primary key (Cid));

create table Employee2(eid char(3), ename char(10), salary number(7,2), 
mid char(3),primary key
(eid), foreign key (mid) references Employee2);

create table ArtObject2 (aoid char(3), atitle char(12), artist 
varchar(10), pricea number(8,2), primarykey (aoid));

create table MakesD2 (aoid char(3), eid char(3), cid char(3), prices 
number, dates date, primary key
(aoid,CID), foreign key (aoid) references ArtObject2, foreign key (CID) 
references Customer2,foreign key (eid) references Employee2);
```

How would you do this query?
List the names of managers of the employees dealing with Chagall paintings.

I have this so far

```
select e.ename
FROM  Employee2 e
inner join MakesD2 md
    on md.eid = e.eid
inner join  ArtObject2 a
    on a.aoid = md.aoid
where a.artist = 'Chagall';
```

here are the tables [http://imgur.com/a/toq3B](https://imgur.com/a/toq3B) and https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NG4D.jpg
I have to get Wilson and Loftus but I get Smith two times.

Comment: http://www.azquotes.com/quote/1043655

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output in the form of formatted text in the question

Comment: i added the tables

Comment: This is not how you use Stack Overflow. You mark an answer as accepted and leave the answered question in place so that others with a similar problem can search for it and find answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m Guessing that Managers and Employees are Custumer and Employees Table;

So the query should be

```
select emp.ename,cus.cname from Employee2 emp
inner join MakesD2 ma
        on ma.eid = emp.eid
inner join  ArtObject2 art
        on art.cid = ma.CID
inner join Customer2 cus
        on cus.Cid = ma.CID
where art.artist = "Chagall"
```

-- Edit 
I commit a Mistake, now I got the Problem

I think that will be enough

```
select distinct emp2.ename from Employee2 emp
inner join Employee2 emp2
        on emp.mid = emp2.eid 
inner join MakesD2 ma
        on ma.eid = emp.eid
inner join  ArtObject2 art
        on art.cid = ma.CID
inner join Customer2 cus
        on cus.Cid = ma.CID
where art.artist = "Chagall"
```

Comment: Could you Provide sample data please?

Comment: samples are posted.

Comment: You have 2 smiths(E02 and E06) Registered in Empoyee table, both has a   record in MakesD2 table. I think that is the problem

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the records of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
select em.ename 
from Employee2 emp
inner join MakesD2 ma
    on ma.eid = emp.eid
inner join  ArtObject2 art
    on art.cid = ma.CID
inner join Customer2 cus
    on cus.Cid = ma.CID
inner join Employee2 em
on em.eid = emp.mid
where art.artist = "Chagall"
```